# How to get started with TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

How to get start TensorFlow, is there any book to read?
I'm good at java programming, and have some background of machine learning. I'd like to find a book or a course about TensorFlow. Is there any recommendation?

Comment: Unfortunately asking for book recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Though this page its not the right place to ask such question , A programmer should get answer wherever possible

You can get some of the tutorials that could be taken as initiation for your study at the very its own website https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/ .Also you can refer the youtube https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxePmhCQRxb9I6tlcB1yJpOq5_4ryCy7n .

provided below is the github repository link where you can find

https://github.com/jtoy/awesome-tensorflow#video

- Books
- Models/Projects
- Libraries
- Videos
- Papers
- Blog posts
- Tutorials